# Grandpa's Crazy Math. Yes? No?

Tags: knowledge, lateral-thinking

"This is really straightforward if you are from the other side of the pond", said Grandpa.

"Put your lateral thinking hat on and prove this to me:

> **Yes x  No = VIIX**

Being from US, this was not straightforward for me. How about you?

Comment: `How about you?` I'm from the other side of the pond and it's quite foggy here. Note to others: rot13(farnxl rqvg #3 vf fhccbfrq gb pynevsl guvatf, fb V nffhzr guvf zhfg or n uvag)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This sounds straightforward if

> Yes = Sí in Spanish
>  No = Nein in German
>  **Sí x**  *Nine* = VI IX or just VIIX

Comment: Tom strikes again. Great